# The sidebar in wp-admin dashboard disappears when viewed on mobile screens in WordPress

Tags: plugins, pages, wp-admin, responsive

I have created a user role called "Customers" through the "Ultimate Member" plugin which has access to only the "Pages", and "Profile" sections in the wp-admin dashboard when they log in. Everything works perfectly fine except responsiveness on mobile screens for the "Customers" role. When the "Customers" log in on a mobile device the menu on the left side in the dashboard containing the links to "Pages" and "Profile" won't appear, but for the "Administrator," the menu appears. As a newbie in the world of WordPress, I made a lot of attempts to fix this but didn't find any success till now. Any help would be highly appreciated! I

Comment: do you have examples of this that you can include in your question? Screenshots? And have you confirmed there are no JS errors for those users when viewing on mobile? Note that you need to phrase your question in such a way that a concrete factual answer can be written, avoid writing open ended questions or discussion prompts

Comment: I solved that issue sir. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the solution so that others can learn too? The site will keep suggesting this question to people trying to find you an answer

Comment: Sure, Sir. I used ADMINIMIZE plugin and checked the option "Enable Sidebar for User Role (Customers)" and it appeared.

Comment: I mean as an answer using the big box below with the post your answer button, not a comment, you don't get points for comment upvotes

Comment: I did it sir. Thank you for cognizing me!

Answer (score 0):

I used **ADMINIMIZE** plugin and checked the option "Enable Sidebar for User Role (Customers)" and it appeared